# SQL Accessing SAS Variable in Query

Tags: sql, db2, sas

I'm attempting to use SASDOS in my statement below, but it's failing to be found. My understanding is that I have to use a form of derived table to access this new column. Is this correct? If so, could someone please help elaborate on how to do that?

```
proc sql;
   create table TEST as 
   select 
      DQBBDA AS 'Sbm Date'n,
      case when 'Sbm Date'n > 999999
         then input('1' || substr(put('Sbm Date'n,z8.),3), z7.)
      end as SASDOS format=z7.
   from 
      DB2SCHEMA.ORIGIN
   where 
      SASDOS = 1130314;
quit;
```

Comment: Can you say what specifically isn't working? Looks like there are a couple of candidates in there, but keen to know what you're attempting. For starters though, since `'Sbn Date'` is just `DQBBDA`, you don't need to reference its new name in the `case` statement; also, you should use `WHERE CALCULATED SASDOS=1130314`  for the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sasfrog commented, you need to add the CALCULATED keyword to refer to a new column in SAS SQL and you should refer to the native DB2 column in your query.  For example:

```
proc sql;
    create table TEST as 
    select DQBBDA AS 'Sbm Date'n
         , case when DQBBDA > 999999
                then input('1' || substr(put(DQBBDA,z8.),3), z7.)
            end as SASDOS format=z7.
    from DB2SCHEMA.ORIGIN
    WHERE CALCULATED SASDOS = 1130314;
quit;
```

However, you really should rethink what you are doing and figure out how to write a `WHERE` clause that uses **only** columns from DB2; otherwise the entire table must be pulled back to SAS (a likely poor solution).  Cases like this are probably better solved using a **pass-thru** query (where you can execute native SQL directly in DB2).

**UPDATE:** Here is another (tested) example using a SAS data set rather than a table from a LIBNAME reference.  Notice I'm also correcting a syntax error with the `input` function (the last parameter should be `7.` not `z7.`).

```
data ORIGIN;
  DQBBDA = 11130314; output;
  DQBBDA = 22130314; output;
run;
options validvarname=any;
proc sql;
    create table TEST as 
    select DQBBDA AS 'Sbm Date'n
         , case when DQBBDA > 999999
                then input('1' || substr(put(DQBBDA,z8.),3), 7.)
            end as SASDOS format=z7.
    from ORIGIN
    WHERE CALCULATED SASDOS = 1130314;
quit;
```

Comment: Unfortunately my DB2 does not have test search support installed and thus I cannot use SQL Pass-Through for my query (the original query in my question is a small version of what I actually use). However, when I try to add CALCULATED in front of SASDOS I receive an error: `ERROR: The following columns were not found as CALCULATED references in the immediate query: SASDOS.`

Comment: @sasfrog I should also note that I'm actually performing this action in an INNER JOIN, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @NickBetcher If you got that error message you must have typed something wrong.  I'll update the answer with a working example using a SAS data set.

Comment: the error only occurs on an INNER JOIN statement, but doesn't occur on a regular WHERE clause.

Comment: I'm marking the answer as correct, because it is in fact correct for the question asked. :) In the event anyone else is interested though: you cannot use calculated values on INNER JOIN's ON clause. A solution in this case is to move the calculation into the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than *where calculated sasdos* you should use *having sasdos*